# How do i use the text in TextField in a block inside UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uialertcontroller

I have a UIAlertController, which contains a textfield and 2 buttons: OK and Cancel. i want to retrieve the text that the user entered in the textfield when he presses OK, but because the textfield is in a block i cant access the textField.text field that is inside the block from the OK button block. how do i access it and use the text entered by the user? see my code below.

```
    - (IBAction)saveItinerary:(id)sender
{
    NSString *itineraryNameInput = [[NSString alloc] init];
    UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                  alertControllerWithTitle:@"Save Itinerary"
                                  message:@"Enter Name for the Itinerary"
                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
    {

    }];

    UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
    {
        [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }];

    [alert addAction:ok];
    [alert addAction:cancel];

    [alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"Name";
        textField.text = itineraryNameInput;
    }];

    NSLog(@"name = %@", itineraryNameInput);

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Did you try to set an instance variable (strong property for example) and set it to point to the textfield? `@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *myAlertTextField;` in your view controller and then `self.myAlertTextField = textField;` inside the block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `textFields` property of the `UIAlertController`.

```
UITextField *textField = alert.textFields.firstObject;
```

Comment: hi, first of all thank you! second, i tried this inside the OK button block, like this:
UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
    {
        UITextField *textFromUser = alert.textFields.firstObject;
        textFromUser.text = itineraryNameInput;
        NSLog(@"name = %@", itineraryNameInput);
    }];
but when i NSLog the var it doesnt show anything. any ideas?

Comment: Try `itineraryNameInput = textFromUser.text;` instead of `textFromUser.text = itineraryNameInput;`.

Comment: i made the itineraryNameInput a property and switched the places of the textfield.text and the self.itinerartNameInput and it worked like a charm! thank you so much @paulvs!